# $scope push is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have some code like:

```
$scope.offer = [];
function offer (Details) {
  angular.forEach(Details, function (product) {
    $scope.offer = SomeAPI.ById.query({ product: id }, function (response) {
      $scope.offer.push(response);
    });
  });
  console.log($scope.offer);
}
```

Error in console：$scope.offer.push is not a function.

Comment: use scope.offer = [ ]

Comment: Sorry forgot that, "$scope.offer = [];" was been already setted up, but still not a function.

Comment: please update question then .

Comment: show us in a fiddle/plunker

Comment: If use like "$scope.offer = response; ", it works. But doesn't work if use "push"

Answer (score 2):

Initialize the array before you push the value,

```
 $scope.offer = [];
angular.forEach(Details, function (product) {     
    $scope.offer = SomeAPI.ById.query({ product: id }, function (response) {
      $scope.offer.push(response);
    });
  });
```

Comment: Sorry, "$scope.offer = [];" already exist, but still same error.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you assigning '$scope.offer' to return type of API call.

```
 $scope.offer = SomeAPI.ById.query({ product: id }, function (response) {
```

This changes the type of '$scope.offer' from '[]' array type to probably a promise object which that api is returning. Thats why push method is not working for you.

Correct code should be:

```
$scope.offer = [];
function offer (Details) {
  angular.forEach(Details, function (product) {
   SomeAPI.ById.query({ product: id }, function (response) {
      $scope.offer.push(response);
    });
  });
  console.log($scope.offer);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, "$scope.offer" could be use out of function, but when I try to console.log($scope.offer) inside the function, It console an empty "[ ]", do you know why?

Comment: Because inside function, your api has not received the response yet. Your api is getting response asynchronously. Before your api gets the response your console.log statement is been executed.